# ANGULAR 12 .¿Como crear una variable en el template .html, sin necesidad declararla como propiedad en el AppComponent.ts?

Tags: html, angular, template

he visto en videos que crean variables en la plantilla `html`, sin necesidad de tener que crearlas como propiedad en el  `AppComponent.ts`, tengo la **versión 12** de `angular`, lo que quiero con este post es ver si me pueden ayudar diciéndome porqué no puedo crear una variable en el `template`, les dejare un ejemplo en una imagen con el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error dice que la propiedad no existe en el `AppComponent.ts` y se que puedo crear esa variable hay mismo, pero he visto en varios videos donde la crean sin problemas EJEMPLO: [Video Ejemplo miren a partir del minuto 3:33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojKeZoGd9i0&list=PLPl81lqbj-4JaLibWSbTVrYTyHDadppKq&index=13)

Por favor si alguien sabe porque me da ese error, o otra manera de crear la variable sin tener que declararla en el `Component.ts` ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngIf` recibe una expresión que pueda resolverse a un valor booleano para poder tomar una decisión.

Ejemplos de expresiones válidas:

```
*ngIf="0" // puede resolverse a false
*ngIf="1" // puede resolverse a true
*ngIf="metodoQueDevuelveUnValorBooleano()"
*ngIf="variableDeComponente1 > variableComponente2"
*ngIf="false"
```

En los ejemplos anteriores, todos resuelven a un valor booleano `false` o `true`. Por eso en el video que compartes no se declara una variable sino que se usa directamente el valor `false`. Similar a usar `1` o `0`,  son literales no variables.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero lo que sucede es que lo que hacen en el video no puedo hacerlo porque me da un error, que mostré en la imágen, al momento de crear el evento ```click``` se crea la ```variable``` **show**, en caso de que no sea un booleano, también pasaría lo mismo, el punto es que no puedo hacer lo mismo porque me da un error.

Comment: Es error de quién hizo el video. La variable ya estaba declarada en el componente en el momento que él la usó.

Comment: ok, gracias por la respuesta eso quería saber ya que no entendía porque sucedía.